# Rendering XML output in Grails

Tags: xml, grails, render

I have a domain class called paymentMethods..

For REST services, I want to send paymentMethods as XML format.

Using

```
render paymentMethods as XML
```

I can send. But I don't want to send some confidential data like cardNumber. How can i remove some particular tags from that XML.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You have two options - Either register custom ObjectMarshaller for XML converter so that it doesnt ourput properties that you dont want to expose. or you can use Groovy's Markup builder to build the xml as you wish.

If you wish to use render As XML - you will need to create a custom ObjectMarshaller that exposes properties of your choice

1. See this article for how to register custom [ObjectMarshaller](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.in/2010/02/grails-xml-conversion.html)
2. And this for [Groovy markup builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

Check this:
[Custom string formatting in Grails JSON marshaller](http://jwicz.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/grails-custom-xml-marshaller/)

It's quite easy to adapt it for your task by adding

```
implements ObjectMarshaller<XML>
```

instead

```
implements ObjectMarshaller<JSON>
```

You can specify some names for properties to skip.

Also check this post:[Grails custom XML Marshaller](http://jwicz.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/grails-custom-xml-marshaller/)